# Remove dashes and leading zeros from a string

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anyone know how to remove the zeros and dashes in MySQL stored procedure. I want to convert this `00000000-0000-0000-0843-243219876432` to this `843243219876432`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SendDistance]
@DeviceImei VARCHAR(50),
@Distance VARCHAR(MAX),
@DateTime VARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN 
 insert into dbo.Location values (
 @DeviceImei,
 0  ,
 0,
 @Distance,
 @DateTime  
 )
 select REPLACE(@DeviceImei,'0','') From dbo.Device where @DeviceImei = Imei



end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do try this:-

```
DECLARE @n NVARCHAR(max)='00000000-0000-0000-0843-243219876432'

SELECT CAST(REPLACE(@n,'-','') AS NUMERIC(38,0))
                      -- OR
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(@n,'-','') AS BIGINT)
```

Comment: What if there are just too many digits to fit inside decimal/bigint?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with REGEXP_REPLACE()

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('00000000-0000-0000-0843-243219876432', '[0/-]+', '')
```

Comment: Might want to add that it requires MySQL 8 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `REPLACE` with `CAST` int.

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('00000000-0000-0000-0843-24321987643','-','')  AS unsigned)
```

if there are some `0` after `24321987643` it can also work.